# OLEFormat (unknown member): Invalid Request in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am using this particular code by Belisarius:

```
Sub a()

Dim oSl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape

Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(1)

With oSh.OLEFormat.Object.WorkSheets(1)
    .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A1").Value + 1
    .Range("A2").Value = .Range("A2").Value - 1
End With

Set oSl = Nothing
Set oSh = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've embedded a line chart (with the ability to change values in excel) using insert menu in PowerPoint 2010.  I'm getting an error that says OLEFormat (unknown member): Invalid Request.  I know this has worked for someone out there but apparently what I've inserted is not an object. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the underlying Excel worksheet is a little tricky - try this approach instead

```
  Sub Test()
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim myChartData As ChartData
Dim myWorkBook As Object
Dim myWorkSheet As Object

Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart
Set myChartData = myChart.ChartData

myChartData.Activate

Set myWorkBook = myChartData.Workbook
Set myWorkSheet = myWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

With myWorkSheet
    .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A1").Value + 1
    .Range("A2").Value = .Range("A2").Value - 1
End With
myWorkBook.Close
Set myWorkBook = Nothing
End Sub
```