# VBA Chart automation using ActivateChartDataWindow

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm building a chart automation script in powerpoint and i have any issue when calling upon "ActivateChartDataWindow".

I would use "Activate" instead of "ActivateChartDataWindow", but "Activate" loads the full Excel program and makes the whole routine run slow and ulgy.

The problem I have is that "ActivateChartDataWindow" does work to populate the charts, but when I manually go to edit the data - right click, edit data - to access the excel application, it does not seem to want to load!

It has been driving my crazy for the last 5 hours and would appreciate any ideas on how to over come this.

OLE.dlll are working correctly and the code I am using is given below.

Code below:

There are 5 slides with one chart on each page and the code below is what i am using as a point of concept

I have a felling i am using "ActivateChartDataWindow" wrong, but there is not much on the web to know what i am doing wrong! Arrrhhhh!

```
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set instance = Nothing
        Set instance = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData
        With instance
            .ActivateChartDataWindow
            instance.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H26").Value = 27
            instance.Workbook.Close
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use `ActivateWhatever` at all? It's better to work directly with the object, no need to `.Activate` it.

Comment: From my understanding, you need to activate the darn thing ! Unless I'm wrong ?

Comment: No, you don't need to. Please try my answer below.

Comment: Will do. Ole objects here I come - many thanks Ash.

Answer (score 1):

As always recommended, you don't need to `Activate` an object to modify it. If you're trying to handle a Workbook embedded in a slide, you can do it this way

```
' This function will get you a Workbook object embedded in a Slide (late binding)
Function getEmbeddedWorkbook(sld As Slide) As Object
    Dim shp As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = 3 Then ' embedded chart workbook created in PP
           Set getEmbeddedWorkbook = shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook
           Exit Function
        End If
        If shp.Type = 7 Then ' embedded workbook pasted from excel
            Set getEmbeddedWorkbook = shp.OLEFormat.Object
            Exit Function
        End If
   Next
End Function


' For Testing, I have 6 slides, Some have a workbook pasted from Excel
' OLE, shape type = 7, others have a chart created in PP (type = 3)
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Object, i As Long
    For i = 6 To 6 'ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set wb = getEmbeddedWorkbook(ActivePresentation.Slides(i))
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D5").Value = i * i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi ash, Thanks for the heads up. I will definitely give this ago. However,  the workbook is embedded in the chart.  Would this code still work ? I am looking at the line .... shp.OLEFormat.Object) = "Workbook" that references the workbook as the Typename

Comment: p.s. I suppose you're pasting the table in PP using `PasteSpecial --> Excel Worksheet`, right?

Comment: Yes. I am guessing you are going to suggest a better way ?

Comment: No, just making sure we're working on the same setup :)

Comment: Thanks for you help so far but the code  you provided does seem to work.

Comment: The same hick up outlined here with the suggestted soluation not being the desirable one -  ACTIVATE !!!!!    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978867/oleformat-unknown-member-invalid-request-in-powerpoint

Comment: back to square one...:(

Comment: hmm. you mean does *not* seem to work, I guess. Well, I'd personally try a million things before I "give up" to use anything matching `Activate`, lol. The thing is my code works well for me, I wish to know what's different in your test case. Any other details would be desirable.

Comment: i am using a 64 bit system and 2016 office

Comment: The code is in the vba powerpoint editor and not in Excel. This makes the charts derived from PP's default charts as oppose to charts copied from Excel

Comment: But how were those charts created? In my case, I copy a range in Excel, go to PP, use `Paste Special` and select `Excel Worksheet...`. This is important, I dont want PP to paste it as its own `Chart` type.

Comment: The machine at my hand now has Office 2007, that's why I dont have the `.Chart` property of the Shape pbject :(. It's handling perfectly the code using .OleFormat.Object though

Comment: Hi again. Now I see why we were talking about different things. will take a look at it again.

Comment: Changed the above code to return the workbook object according to shape type. Code works for me without `Activate`. (Office+ 2013 64 bits, Win8 Pro).

Comment: Thanks for helping me work through this. The issue I found when working with the chart.chartdata.workbook was that when you open and close the chart via the right click and edit data button is that the values in the workbook return to what they were before.

Comment: Everywhere I look it suggests to over come this you need to use the "Activate" method which is ugly and slow. 

However, "ActivateChartDataWindow" does not load the full version of Excel and it is more "silent".  The issue I have is that when running the sub routine it does  not allow for the charts to be edited manually via the right click edit chart data.

Comment: If I was to rephrase the issue such that it focuses on the "ActivateChartDataWindow" method.


For example, when using the "....Chartdata.Activate" method it is paired with the "Workbook.Close" method.


What would be the equivalent to "...Workbook.close" when using "ActivateChartDataWindow". I assume this is why the error is occurring - cannot open the chart manually after running the sub routine.

I have Googled the hell out of  "ActivateChartDataWindow" and not much information is available.

Comment: Also, when pairing "ActivateChartDataWindow" and ...WorkBook.Close it works well in step through mode - pressing F8 - and allows for manually editing, but not when you run it as a sub routine!

This is genuinely driving me mad!

Comment: At my end, just this macro:  `ActivePresentation.Slides(6).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow` does open the chart for editing by hand (for a chart created in PP, not pasted from Excel) and the changes are applied. Make sure you're doing it for *only one chart at a time*. (In addition, to we having # Office versions though, but yours is even newer).

Comment: Interestingly, the `Edit Data` option is available in the session when I create the chart... When I save the presentation and close then reopen, the option is gone. I'm not talking about VB, but the GUI of VB. Do you have the same behavior?

Comment: On the other hand, Excel linked charts seem somehow more stable.

Comment: Kind of. So when i ran the sub using "ActivateChartDataWindow" and then try to open the chart WorkBook - using both codes below - I get the following error "Run-Time 7 out of memory"

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow
 
or 
 
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData.Activate